# Table with no options Issue

Tags: javascript

Would be grateful if anyone could provide clarification on below issue related to tables.

`Issue1`: Here is a SPA with table `plunker1`:http://plnkr.co/edit/LJ81NedMa88Q7EhFrLmw?p=preview (View Tab2, pick a date and submit for the table to generate)
This is fine and I have included the same in other `plunker2`:http://plnkr.co/edit/GY7r7kDqqaTzGONRaF3z?p=preview (View Tab2,again click on tab2, pick a date and submit for the table to generate), but I couldn't get the calendar when clicked on it and after clicking on submit the table is not displayed with options as search, refresh, toggle. Why is this so? Have I included script files in a wrong way?

Comment: the table work in plnkr 1 and 2 the only problem is your plnkr nr 2 date picker

Comment: @madalinivascu: But the table in plunker2 is not with bootstrap options as in plunker1

Comment: in my browser is see the table as in plunker 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for the first bit why date time picker is not working:

I see that you have included the angular.js CDN twice in `line 9` and in `line 22`.

The version of second angular `<script data-require="angular.js@1.1.x" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.js" data-semver="1.1.5"></script>` is `1.1.5` and

`$validators` is only valid from version `1.3` which is pointing correcting in your first CDN `line 9` .

So just remove your second CDN from line 22 and your date time picker should work. This should even fix the display of table options such as search, refresh, toggle

Comment: Thanx a lot.. but removing that has changed the style of calendar.. how can this be corrected??

Comment: just copy the contents of `StyleSheet1.css` in `plunker 1` to `style.css` in `plunker 2`

Comment: The easier way would be to change scopes of all your dropdown include the `machine id` . But the correct way would be restructure your entire code to include, each machine id as unique record in dropdowns. The  second method will help you see thing more clearly.

Comment: @Pranitha just post a new question here (on SO) and I'm pretty sure there are plenty of awsome people around here  who would be more than happy to help you. Right now I'm quite busy. Will have a look at the plunker when i get chance. Cheers